# Please add a 'Migrate to Meta.StackOverflow.com' link on SO

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, migration

It'd be nice if question owners could flag their own closed questions for migration from the other StackOverflow sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be nice if users could migrate even non-closed questions.

Answer (score 4):

"Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com" is a close option, now. Jeff will have to confirm if it auto-migrates like the serverfault.com option does.

Not sure about the old posts, though.  I think they may just have to be reposted, or manually moved by Jeff, et al.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently possible for moderators to move questions over here from either SO or SF. Your best bet would be to flag your post and ask for it to be moved. If the moderator agrees, they will move the question for you.

I believe that there are features in the works for mass migration, but as long as you have just two or three you want moved over this solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's just posted [this on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/) describing the new migration process.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF, the problem is how do you move one that's closed already?

Comment: Don't know - e-mail team@stackoverflow.com or flag it?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask the following question but I think it belongs here.

**Why not let people with 'x' amount of rep vote to migrate from the current site (SO/SF/MS/SU) to one of the others?**

This would take the manual work out of it, remove the burden from moderators, and still have a safety mechanism built in just like 'vote to close'.

Comment: This is already done. :) If you vote to close a question as "belongs to ...." it gets moved to that site if that's the winning close reason.

Comment: I must have been reading old posts, I don't have enough rep to do that yet =)