# Reverse "Please add a 'Migrate to Meta.StackOverflow.com' link on SO"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, migration, migration-path-request

Now that the SO site has matured, can we please remove the migration link to Meta?

This would be the opposite of [Please add a 'Migrate to Meta.StackOverflow.com'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/please-add-a-migrate-to-meta-stackoverflow-com-link-on-so).

OR

Can we remove the five site migration restriction?

OR

Can we swap the Meta with [codereview.se]?

[Edit to provide my reasoning]

> Why?

Because SO has five perfectly valid migration sites now. Many people ask questions related to computing in general, or code review, etc. Given the five site limitation on migrations the utility of Meta is not as high as other options that could be provided. See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66732/some-migration-target-data) from @ConradFrix (minus the months) for the numbers.

Keeping Meta over one of the other programming sites demonstrably decreases the utility of the SO site by leaving off topic questions in place, and retards the utility of other sites because relevant content is not directed there and instead left in the giant bucket of SO.

Comment: Any reason for this? Meta is a standard migration path for every site.

Comment: @lunboks Ultimately because SO has five perfectly valid migration sites now.  Many people ask questions related to computing in general, or code review, etc.  However, I have seen a dwindling number of questions about the site itself.  I would suspect this to be the case as any site matures.  I understand the need as the community matures, but I see it greatly reduced once a community has established its norms.

Comment: I can see how a migration path to Code Review would be useful, but Meta is the most important of the five, in my opinion.

Comment: Downvotes?  This `community` is overrun by a bunch of curmudgeons.

Comment: [Votes are different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) And what of Earth is a curmudgeon?

Comment: You do of course realize that [votes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), right?

Comment: @Dennis and Bart, I did not and thank you. I still hold that an answer or comment about why something is a bad idea would be more helpful.

Comment: @Dennis [__curmudgeon__, _noun_: a bad-tempered, difficult, cantankerous person](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/curmudgeon)

Comment: It's a bad idea because this exact same sentiment has been asked in about a thousand other Meta questions. Everyone wants to add more sites to the migration options. The only thing *different* about your proposal, is that you want to remove Meta as an option, which is a profoundly stupid idea because Meta is one of the standard migration paths that is unlocked on *all* sites. And there are a good number of questions that get migrated from main to meta. A lot of people don't read the FAQ, just like a lot of people don't search before asking a question.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: I downvoted because I was touched inappropriately by a duck once.

Comment: "However, I have seen a dwindling number of questions about the site itself."  Meta gets (41) questions per day more than Programmers.se (35) or codereview (9.5) By this argument Programmers.SE should be removed and Codereview should never be added.

Comment: @TheEstablishment that's odd, I searched through the questions twice before posting... those thousands of questions must have been hiding out on SO proper!

Comment: @ConradFrix thank you for posting the numbers, I'll correct my perceptions.

Comment: @Conrad, it's not really about the number of questions Meta gets. It's about the number of questions Stack Overflow gets that *should have* been at Meta instead. How many SO questions are migrated here per day, and how many are migrated elsewhere? And how many are closed without migration because the desired destination isn't an option?

Comment: @RobKennedy I assumed that was what Conrad meant.  Meta gets 41 questions per day _migrated from SO_, and the same for the others he listed.  But then I now have to wonder how CodeReview gets those questions migrated, since the path does not exist...

Comment: @Robkennedy The OP suggested that questions on meta were dwindling. My comment was to address that. To get what you're talking about you'd need to look at something like [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66731/some-migration-target-data)

Comment: @ConradFrix, actually I was referring to Rob's view. And your query shows exactly what I was attempting to claim, although I admittedly did so poorly.  As time goes on migration from SO to the other sites, such as SuperUser and DBA have increased, while the number migrated to Meta is comparatively small.

Comment: @lunboks To add to my first response, and in echo of my comment on the answer below, given the five site limitation on migrations the utility of Meta is not as high as the other options provided, and that keeping Meta over one of the other programming sites demonstrably decreases the utility of the SO site by leaving off topic questions in place.  See [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66732/some-migration-target-data) from Conrad Frix (minus the months) for the  numbers.

Comment: Code Review migrations are all handled by moderators. Also I'm pretty sure that SE won't set up a migration path to it while it's still in beta.

Comment: I didn't get the impression Joshua meant questions on Meta were dwindling, just the meta-questions asked on Stack Overflow (since those are the ones relevant to a question about migration). Yours is exactly the type of query I was hoping to see, @Conrad, but the results are completely wrong. It says there was only one SO-to-Meta migration in all of 2011, and only five migrations to other sites. It says the only SO-to-Programmers migration was asked in March 2011, but I know of one asked in June.

Comment: @GhostUser That's correct. All other issues aside, user-driven migration paths to or from beta sites don't happen.

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with your proposal, since I don't see why a migration path to Meta would *only* be useful in the early days of a site.

Who is the typical user that posts in the wrong site? New users. And they come continuously, especially on a huge site like SO, so you can assume that some of them might post a question on the main site, since they don't know the structure Main <-> Meta.

If you remove that migration path, there wouldn't be any solution other than just closing those questions and inviting the users to post here. Then these users might not understand it right away, plus you'll have a lot of clutter on the main site, due to the closed stuff, etc.

It's much simpler and logic to keep the migration path, after all.

**Edit**: About the "OR" in your question, I replied to the first one, now the other two:

> Can we remove the five site migration restriction?

The migration restriction exists only for regular users (I doubt it will be removed), moderators [can  migrate anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71350/176533).

> Can we swap the Meta with [codereview.se]?

This is again asking to remove Meta. If necessary, you can ask to *add* codereview.se to the options, but add it, not use it to replace the Meta option.

Comment: +1 for writing out why you object.

Comment: As for why I feel that it would be more useful in the early days of a site, that is when the site itself is still undefined.  Just like the beta sites often have questions about how they should handle new things that they've encountered, such as where to migrate off-topic questions.  But once those norms are defined people, in a general sense, become familiar with them.  I'd be willing to bet that Google gets fewer queries today on how to use Google than when they first launched.  If the norms of the community are not being exported then we are doing a poor job of expressing them.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake That is true for the regulars. But new users have a little more legitimacy in not knowing the rules. Sure, they should read the FAQ and all, but I'd close an eye on a new user mistake, as it can happen. And this wrong posting is one of those mistakes, so why remove a perfectly functioning solution? It works, it's the simplest one, why remove it?

Comment: Hence, the following OR statements in the question.

Comment: I'll include that in the answer.

Comment: Given the query posted by @ConradFrix I can see that my claim about the decrease in questions migrated to Meta, is clearly false. I still argue, however, that its utility is not as high as the other options provided, and that keeping Meta over one of the other programming sites is a bad idea.